# How to prep 90 yr old plaster for new paint?

Tags: painting, plaster, preparation

I’ve just peeled old wallpaper off 90 year old plaster walls. The plaster is in good shape with some vertical cracks where a two walls meet (in each corner). I’d like to patch the cracks and paint.

Please help! I’m a total newbie and want to learn what not to do (and what to do)! Thank you for your support.[image]

Comment: Your picture is very small - it's hard to see what you're up against. I suspect some filler and maybe some primer paint would be enough to get going though. Just make sure the wall really is smooth - you'll see every lump and bump when repainted.